# How can I Append the Id attribute Selector or Store the Id in Jquery variable and use that variable as selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, pug

I want to perform show/hide operation on textarea element on clicking the replay button using id as selector in jquery but my id is in the form `id = "textarea"+dat.description_id` i.e dat.description_id is the value that i have concate. and also I have put this element in loop so there are many textarea field on the page.

```
        -if(data.length > 0)
            each dat in data
              form(action="/update/"+dat.description_id, method="post")
                tr
                  td #{dat.description_id}
                  td #{dat.applied_date}
                  td #{dat.fullname}
                  td 
                  td #{dat.complaint_name}
                  td #{dat.complaint}
                  td
                    div(style="display:flex")
                      -if(dat.status == 'Done')
                        p #{dat.replay}
                      -else
                        textarea(name="replay" id="textarea"+dat.description_id class="form-control" cols="30", rows="2")
                        button(type="submit" id="replay-btn"+dat.description_id  class="btn btn-primary m-2" onclick="myfun()") Reply
```

By performing the Below Jquery Code there is no event occuring on page. According to me if I we can store the Id in the jquery variable we can do that thing but the question is how to use that variable as the selector OR ELSE how to append that `dat.description_id` in `$("textarea")`.
PLESE tell ME the SOLUTION for this PRoblem......

```
script.
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("textarea").hide();
          $('#replay-btn').click(function(){
            $("#textarea").toggle();
          });

          $("#textarea").keyup(function(){
            var len = $(this).val().length;
            if(len > 0)
            {
              $("#replay-btn").attr('type','submit');
            }
            else{
              $("#replay-btn").attr('type','button');
            }
          })
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create a `data-controls` attribute on the `button` element that matches the `id` of the corresponding `textarea` element. Then you could add a `js-reply-button` class to the `button` elements to bind the jQuery events.

I would recommend rewriting your Pug `else` statement as follows:

```
else
  textarea.js-reply-textarea.form-control(id=`textarea_${dat.description_id}`, name='reply', cols='30', rows='2')
  button.js-reply-button.btn.btn-primary.m-2(data-controls=`textarea_${dat.description_id}`, type='submit') Reply
```

With this structure, your jQuery to show/hide each text area when someone clicks the reply button could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide the textarea elements
  $('.js-reply-textarea').hide();
  // when a user clicks the reply button
  $('.js-reply-button').click(function() {
    // get the value of the button's data-controls attribute
    let textareaId = $(this).attr('data-controls');
    // use it to target and toggle the right textarea element
    $('#' + textareaId).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: This Solution works Thankyou Friend . I would  also like to one more suggestion that now I also had problem that when the textarea is empty the replay button should have `type = button` and when the user will write in textarea field the button attribute change to `type = submit`. Can I have the solution for this...

Comment: You should probably create a separate submit button for that. If you need additional help with a related issue, please create a new question.

Comment: Friend I got the solution. Not need to create separate button. I have used the same logic that u have given for the last question. Thaking you....